# Trouble with Chainlink External Adapter making an API call to Spotify

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I made an external adapter from the [Javascript External Adapter Template from Chainlink](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template), trying to use the Client Credentials flow for Spotify's API to return artist data, documentation listed below.
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow
https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-artist/

and I am able to make the call just fine with this code through Axios [image: Returns expected data]

but when I try to run the same call through the External Adapter which uses Axios for it's API calls as well, I get this error.
[image: The URL and Header object is being output in the console.]

Here is a snippet of the main code of the external adapter from index.js

```html
const customParams = {
  artist: [''],
  
  endpoint: false
}

const createRequest = (input, callback) => {
  // The Validator helps you validate the Chainlink request data

  const apiID = process.env.API_ID
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY

  let token = 'BQDlkzka093OuR4tL7XyaI-Tag4R166FQGBSogBP6hEBxhsCjH8XfMRqs_apKFk0T87FGIrwPtT1bkuGCeE';


  const validator = new Validator(callback, input, customParams)
  const jobRunID = validator.validated.id
  const endpoint = validator.validated.data.endpoint
  const artistID = validator.validated.data.artist.toUpperCase()
  const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/${artistID}`

  const params = {
    artistID
  }

  // curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer authtoken" 

  
  // This is where you would add method and headers
  // you can add method like GET or POST and add it to the config
  // The default is GET requests
  // method = 'get' 
  // headers = 'headers.....'
  const head = {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
  }
 
  const config = {
    url,
    headers: head
  }
  console.log("config:", config)
```

and this is the command I am running in the terminal to pass in the Spotify Artist ID

```html
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ "id": 0, "data": { "": "5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x"} }'
```

-Edit-

Just to show that the code isn't all totally wrong, I am able to make a call through the external adapter to this url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5, passing in the 5 with this command.

```html
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ "id": 0, "data": { "": "5"} }'
```

[image: Returns expected data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with this line, making the artist ID all uppercase.

```html
const artistID = validator.validated.data.artist.toUpperCase() // Changed this 
const artistID = validator.validated.data.artist // To this
```

Comment: Nice job on finding that out! You should mark your answer as the correct answer, so others can be sure this issue was properly addressed.